# How can the hover panel in people's directory be modified not to show authored documents

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

I am trying to create a people's directory for my intranet. When I hover over any employee's name I can see their authored documents. I just want this to be a search page for other employees to be able to search for details and contact information of their colleagues. I do not want everyone to see which documents have been written by them.
Here is a screenshot:

[image]

So here in the above picture I don't want anyone to see the authored documents. 
I have tried turning off Sharing activity but this can still be seen.

Is there a way to prevent this to be seen?

Thanks,
Sayali

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the Item_Person.html and Item_Person_HoverPanel.html or BETTER copy them and rename them then make changes to the copies. Simply remove the sections you don't want to see.

Just curious, why do you need to make this change? The search results are security trimmed.

Answer (score 1):

if you still looking to remove the documents completely from the Hover Panel, you can, as Matthew has suggested, copy Item_Person_HoverPanel.html and edit it..look for these 2 lines and comment them

hide the following lines

```
<!--#_                    
                            //if(isExpResult == false) {
_#-->                        
                              <!--<div id="_#= dynTagId =#_"></div>-->
<!--#_                                                                            
                            //}                
_#-->   
                            <!--<div id="_#= dynTagIdRel =#_"></div>-->
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to [Customize search result types in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn135239.aspx)